# UIImageView photo transition effect Xcode 5

Tags: uiimageview, xcode5, slideshow, transition, photo

I want to add a transition effect between images like fade or anything else.

Here's my code:

```
-(IBAction)startSlideShow:(id)sender;
{
self.imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"slide01.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"slide02.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"slide03.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"slide04.png"],
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"slide05.png"],
                                  nil];

self.imageView.animationDuration = 15.0;
self.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[self.imageView startAnimating];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I think you looking for this one,.. [github.com/jberlana/JBKenBurns](http://github.com/jberlana/JBKenBurns)

(or)

I found this on someother search, try this too..

http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content

Other simple way to achieve: Steps to achieve

Add all the images in one scroll view.

Enable paging for that scroll view.

Based on the content offset of the scroll view highlight the appropriate dot(indicator in the bottom).

Comment: Isn't there any simpler way i.e. a single line below my code? I have placed a UIImageView in a View controller and set it as a background. I want to show it as a slideshow with an effect. I don't want it for a user to have gesture recognition.

Comment: @wolfhawk Try this, should helps u a lot https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser

Comment: @wolfhawk Try this too, I think you looking for this one,.. https://github.com/jberlana/JBKenBurns

Comment: I had found the first one in one of my searches. I want it for another view controller of my app. The second one is what I want! Perfect! But how do I implement it in my app? With a simple #import in my ViewController? And I have to change it for an iPhone Version!

Comment: please gothrough with ExampleViewController.h & .m files,.. If you had any further doubts fell free to ask me,..

Comment: I did. I have an UIImage view on the background of my view controller because I want to have a small text in the front. How will I connect it with the code from KenBurns?